# wp_update_term_count_now doesn't work with a custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, tags

I have a custom post type name session and a tag name post_tag.

This is the declaration of my custom post type :

```
function create_posttype()
{

  register_post_type(
    'session',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name'                => __('Sessions'),
        'singular_name'       => __('Session'),
        'menu_name'           => __('Sessions'),
        'all_items'           => __('Toutes les sessions'),
        'view_item'           => __('Voir sessions'),
        'add_new'             => __('Ajouter'),
        'edit_item'           => __('Modifier'),
      ),
      'hierarchical'            => true,
      'public'                  => true,
      'show_in_rest'            => true,
      'supports'                => array('title', 'thumbnail', 'revisions, custom-fields'),
      'taxonomies'              => array('category', 'post_tag'),
      'menu_position'           => 20,
      'menu_icon'               => 'dashicons-groups',
    )
  );

}
add_action('init', 'create_posttype');
```

I need to add a tag, so i do this :

```
wp_set_post_tags($session->ID, "annule", false);
```

It works. But then i have a problem with my total of post type for this tags in the backend. So i do this :

```
$update_taxonomy = 'post_tag';
$get_terms_args = array('taxonomy' => $update_taxonomy,'hide_empty' => false);                      
$update_terms = get_terms($get_terms_args);
wp_update_term_count_now($update_terms,  $update_taxonomy);
```

But this doesn't work.

I suppose i'm doing something wrong. But i don't see what ?

Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't need to manually update the term count if WordPress is loaded correctly. So, when and where do you call `wp_set_post_tags()`? In a hook - what hook, if so?

Answer (score 0):

You pass the array of `WP_Term` objects instead of the array of `term_id`  to the `wp_update_term_count_now()`.

Pass the `fields` argument to `get_terms()` to specify it's output:

```
<?php
$update_taxonomy = 'post_tag';

$get_terms_args = array(
    'taxonomy'   => $update_taxonomy,
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'fields'     => 'ids', // nota bene.
);

$update_terms = get_terms( $get_terms_args ); // get the array of term IDs.

wp_update_term_count_now( $update_terms, $update_taxonomy );
```

See [WP_Term_Query::__construct() parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/#parameters).